# How to run Cypress from Docker?

Tags: docker, cypress

I'm trying to run Cypress tests head(lessly) with Docker.
From tutorial I've followed I've got this command:

`docker run -it -v ~/tdd/services/cypress:/cypress -w /cypress --entrypoint=cypress cypress/included:4.9.0 run`

This throws:

```
Can't run because no spec files were found.

We searched for any files inside of this folder:

/cypress/cypress/integration
```

I keep Cypress directory with all test specs and cypress.json file in absolute path `~/tdd/services/cypress` which is included in the command so Cypress knows what files to add to the container.

structure of the cypress directory:

```
cypress/
    integration/
    cypress.json
    package.json
```

Getting error anyway. Can anyone more rounded in Cypress & Docker assist me on this ?

Dockerfile:

```
FROM cypress/included:4.9.0

WORKDIR /
RUN rm -rf /cypress/integration
ADD integration /cypress/integration
COPY package.json /cypress/package.json
RUN npm install randomstring --save
RUN cypress run
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and add how your `Dockerfile` looks like. I see a problem with `/cypress/cypress/integration`. Basically your spec files not copied in correct directory so I wanted to see how you are copying your files into the directory inside your Dockerfile.

Comment: I'm not using any Dockerfile. The command `docker run -it -v ~/tdd/services/cypress:/cypress -w /cypress --entrypoint=cypress cypress/included:4.9.0 run` should substitute Dockerfile.

Comment: Yes, it is quite clear that it is looking for files in a wrong path `/cypress/cypress/integration` . There's no double cypress directory.

Answer (score 3):

Your cypress structure should look like this:

```
cypress/
    integration/
cypress.json
package.json
```

Or if you want to keep it as you mentioned above because of reasons, then specify this in `cypress.json` file: `"integrationFolder": "integration"`.
This will override the default `cypress/integration` path value, tho I would suggest the first solution.